# Finding Maclaurin series of $\ln(\sqrt{z^2+1}+z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to find Maclaurin series of a function $f(z)=\ln(\sqrt{z^2+1}+z)$. Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: How about the same way you find the Maclaurin series of any function?

Comment: Simply taking derivatives doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

Comment: As in you can't seem to predict the pattern? List the work you've done so far. Right now it seems like you don't know what a Maclaurin series is at all. Once you show your work we'll know where to start helping you from.

Comment: Once you have (correctly) found (and simplified) $f'(z)$ it should be straightforward.

Comment: $f'(0)=1$, $f''(0)=0$, $f'''(0)=-1$, $f^{(4)}(0)=0$, $f^{(5)}(0)=9$

Comment: This is the inverse of the hyperbolic sinus. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_function#Series_expansions for its MacLaurin expansion.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to look-up the series for $\sinh^{-1}(z), \;$
you can compute $f'(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2+1}}=(1+z^2)^{-1/2}\;$  and use 
the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

$$(1+x)^{-1/2} = 1-\tfrac{1}{2}x+\tfrac{3}{8}x^2-\tfrac{5}{16}x^3 +\tfrac{35}{128}x^4-\tfrac{63}{256}x^5 \dots$$
Now substitute $x=z^2$
$$(1+z^2)^{-1/2} = 1-\tfrac{1}{2}z^2+\tfrac{3}{8}z^4-\tfrac{5}{16}z^6 +\tfrac{35}{128}z^8-\tfrac{63}{256}z^{10} \dots$$
and integrate termwise
$$f(z) = z-\tfrac{1}{6}z^3+\tfrac{3}{40}z^5-\tfrac{5}{112}z^7+\tfrac{35}
{1152}z^9-\tfrac{63}{2816}z^{11} \dots$$